# userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:) isn't called

Tags: ios

The app is closed. I tap the remote notification banner to launch the app, the `userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)` method should be called.

My app works correctly on the build version, but failed on TestFlight version.

How can I fix this situation?

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    printD(userInfo)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As [Apple Document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649518-usernotificationcenter) about `userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)`

> Asks the delegate how to handle a notification that arrived while the
>   app was running in the foreground.

So when app closed, your app didn't call **userNotificationCenter** function

Try to catch notification in this case by below code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {

     if launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] != nil {
    // Do your task here
    }

}
```

Comment: I have tapped the notification banner I received, so the app should be launched and the function should be trigger. As I said, it does work on the build version, but doesn't on the TestFlight version.